# How to update the database in spinner when a record is inserted?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-spinner

Here is the code which i use to load the spinner in the **.MainActivity.java**

```
    public void spin() {
    {  
        try{  
            SQL db = new SQL(getBaseContext());  
            db.open();  
            List<String> cursor = db.selectAll();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor);
                s.setAdapter(adapter);  
        }  
        catch(Exception e)  
        {  
        Log.v("Error","e.tostring()");  
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in the **SQL.java** to get the items from the database.

```
    public List<String> selectAll() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = this.mydb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NAME
    }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor !=null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

this is how i add records from another activity **.Addnew.java**

```
case R.id.bsave:
            boolean work=true;
            try{
            String rno1 = rno.getText().toString();
            String name1 = name.getText().toString();
            String reg1 = reg.getText().toString();
            String mob1 = mob.getText().toString();

            SQL entry = new SQL(Addnew.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(rno1,name1,reg1,mob1);
            entry.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                work=false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Naah");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }finally{
                if(work){
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Yeah");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
            break;
```

The problem is when I insert a new record in the database it doesn't show up in the spinner immediately, rather it shows it only after restarting the application. can someone help  me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try refreshing your activity by any one of the method

```
startActivity(getIntent);
```

or

```
Intent addservice1 = new Intent(YourActivity.this,YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(addservice1);
```

It will solve your issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: where you adding this code? try to add this after you inserting the data.. because the same function i am using in my app the spinner get updated when i refresh the activity

Answer (score 3):

Once data has been added to list, please set adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update your spinner content.

It will solve your issue.

Comment: can you show how you are adding?? Only way to update spinner content is to set adpater by calling notifyDataSetChanged Method

Comment: how you are accessing adapter in mainactivity?? Please see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: i've added the code from all three activities. kindly see that

Comment: You  need to add adpater.notifyDataSetChanged() in Addnew.java class. Either make your ArrayAdapter to static ,so that you can access in Addnew Class

Comment: thanks bro.. its kinda complicated for me(beginner), it vl b great if you could explain it wit an example code or something :)